# What does "as" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

> Properly trained safety diver(s) shall be available as determined by
>   the manager.

Sometimes "as" means "when". For example, "as necessary" means "when it is necessary". Then, for the example above, does it "as determined" mean "when it is determined by the manager"? or does it mean "whenever it is needed based on the manager's decision"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that context it has the meaning of "**like**" for example **"All employees should attend the meeting on Friday as previously stated by the manager"**

**As** previously stated means "**like previously stated"**

**As** and **like** sometimes have the same meaning.

Here's a link to help clarify things for you:

[Like vs As](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/like-vs-as/).

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.

Comment: Just edited sir.

Comment: @Kyle - Adding a link like that is not quite the right way to do things. For one thing, that web page could get shut down, meaning the link won’t be useful at all. For another, that website discusses the differences between _like_ and _as_ more than it does the similarities. To fix both of these problems, simply take an excerpt from the website and post it into your answer. That way, if the content of the page changes or disappears, we can all still figure out the point you were driving at.